# Avoid multiple listens to ActiveMQ topic with Spring Boot microservice instances

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, activemq-classic

We have configured our ActiveMQ message broker as a Spring Boot project and there's another Spring Boot application (let's call it `service-A`) that has a listener configured to listen to some topics using `@JmsListener` annotation. It's a Spring Cloud microservice appilcation.

The problem:

- It is possible that `service-A` can have multiple instances running.
- If we have 2 instances running, then any message coming on topic gets listened to twice.
- How can we avoid every instance listening to the topic?
- We want to make sure that the topic is listened to only once no matte the number of `service-A` instances.

Is it possible to run the microservice in a cluster mode or something similar? I also checked out [ActiveMQ virtual destinations](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations) but not too sure if that's the solution to the problem.

We have also thought of an approach where we can decide who's the leader node from the multiple instances, but that's the last resort and we are looking for a cleaner approach.

Any useful pointers, references are welcome.

Comment: Why are you using a topic? If you use a queue then every message is only consumed once

Comment: Agree. However, we need a topic, there are multiple reasons behind it due to which we can't go with queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is a [shared topic subscription](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jms2messaging.html) which was added in JMS 2. Unfortunately ActiveMQ "Classic" doesn't support JMS 2. However, [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) does.

ActiveMQ Artemis is the next generation broker from ActiveMQ. It supports [most of the same features as ActiveMQ "Classic"](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-artemis-roadmap) (including full support for OpenWire clients) as well as many other features that "Classic" doesn't support (e.g. JMS 2, [shared-nothing high-availability using replication](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html#data-replication), [last-value queues](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/last-value-queues.html), [ring queues](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ring-queues.html), [metrics plugins](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html) for integration with tools like Prometheus, [duplicate message detection](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/duplicate-detection.html), etc.). Furthermore, ActiveMQ Artemis is built on a high-performance, non-blocking core which means scalability is much better as well.

Comment: That's not a solution for his problem. As he can't change from topic to queue he may not be able to change the messaging broker

Comment: It's certainly possible that he may not be able to move to a different broker, but he hasn't said that definitively so at this point it's premature to say that this isn't a solution to his problem. Also, he asked for "any useful pointers, references," and that's what this answer is.

Comment: I see. Btw. same did I with recommending queues instead of topics but also this is not an answer just a suggestion

Comment: It is an answer if the questioner accepts it as such.