# How to Prevent Multiple Instances of the Same Microservice Reading the Same Message from an ActiveMQ Artemis Topic

Tags: spring-jms, activemq-artemis, jms-topic

This question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572538/avoid-multiple-listens-to-activemq-topic-with-spring-boot-microservice-instances), but I'm not sure how to get this working

I have an ActiveMQ Artemis Broker v 2.16.0 and Spring microservice projects with spring-jms 5.3.3. I have two microservices, A and B, that subscribe to a topic. Because of high workload, I have two instances of microservice A running. How can I configure both instances of microservice A to connect to the topic but not consume the same messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, every JMS topic subscriber gets every message sent to the topic. However, JMS 2 introduced the concept of a "shared" subscription where 2 subscribers share the same subscription so only one of them will get any particular message. You need to invoke `setSubscriptionShared(true)` when you configure your JMS listener container factory in order to enable this behavior.

Comment: Thanks @justin-bertram

Comment: @CeeTee, glad to help.